# Why is visual studio showing me so many non-errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I look at the output window it says:

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

If I scroll through the text in the output window I can see the error, double click it and it takes me to the error.

In my error list window though (which I would prefer to use) it has many many errors (errors not warnings - with the red symbol). Things like type or namespace cannot be found in places where I know is not in error. When I fix this one error as shown in the output window the error list clears. This seems to happen on and off.

This is in visual studio 2015 - I don't think I had this problem last week when I was using visual studio 2010 but another developer on our team says he always had this happen in visual studio. Maybe there was some setting I ticked in the past but not sure what it might be?

edit: After posting I noticed a dropdown that says "Build+IntelliSense" if I change this to "Build Only" it works how I am used to. So it seems for some reason intellisense doesn't work with our solution.

Comment: What namespaces does it say are missing ?

Comment: Is your build output listing "Build Only" or "Build + Intellisense"?  I've just noticed that I have a solution that builds successfully, but due to intellisense issues, is showing over 12,000 errors.

Comment: Yes it is intellisense issue - thanks @Brendan Green.

Comment: The namespace is one from another project in the solution. This is not the only error just an example.

Comment: Can you tell us one of the errors specifically? It might help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one project getting built, and one fails, all the projects that reference it will show errors everywhere they reference the project.

Once it builds, all these errors will go away again.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have not restored your nuget packages

Comment: Oddly though he still gets it after he has built (he got a build message). Normally NuGet would download before you try to build.

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe we use nuget

Comment: Do you have a packages.config in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Output window for more details on error. For me the error was hidden in output window where it specified which NuGet packet is incompatible with  one of my projects. I had to install a newer version of that NuGet package and that fixed the issue.